# autocmd vs augroup example

Tags: vimrc

Is there any difference between the following two commands:

```
autocmd FileType html,htmldjango inoremap <buffer> <leader>1 &nbsp;
```

And converted to an `autocmd`:

```
augroup filetype_html
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType html,htmldjango inoremap <buffer> <leader>1 &nbsp;
augroup END
```

Is one preferable over the other, or are they two different ways of saying the same thing? If so, why should one be used over the other?

Comment: Before posting 12 questions in a row, please do some researches on this site to make sure you are not creating duplicates. If the built-in search is not enough remember that you can use `site:vi.stackexchange.com` in your favorite search engine to limit the results to our site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `augroup` followed by `autocmd!`. Period.

The major problem is that executing

```
autocmd BufRead * echomsg 'foobar'
```

twice will result in printing `foobar` twice per each `BufRead`.